# How do I get the text() from a function to use in another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to turn an option from a select list into text to then use the text in a function that returns a message topic for Firebase. I have had to use a function to get the text out of the list correctly but I don't know how to then output the text from the function in the second function to be used for the messaging. I can console.log the text, but I don't know what to use to just output the text itself inside the message function. I may be confusing myself a little. Please note: There are const being declared that are being used later on so any comment of "Why are you declaring those consts" won't be helpful. I need to know what to put in the TWO ### WHAT GOES HERE ### blocks to make this work?

I have tried just using jquery's text() to simply output the data I want but that just brings back undefined every time. The only way I've been able to actually get the option text is to place it in a function, but I have to actually DO something with it and I'm not sure what function will give me my desired results.

#### Here is the code

```
const select = $("#schoolSelect");
     selectedOption = function() {
         ### WHAT GOES HERE? ###($("#schoolSelect option:selected").text())
     }
 const stage2 = $("#stage2Div");
 const stage3 = $("#stage3Div");
 const popupClose = $("#popupClose");
 const popup = $("#popup");
 const selectedValues = getSelectValues(select);
 // Alert Buttons Functions

 // Stage 2 Button
 // Sends Soft Lockdown to all devices subscribed

 stage2.click(function() {
     var select = $("#schoolSelect"),
     selectedValues = getSelectValues(select);
         if (selectedValues.length == 0) {
             popup.addClass("show");
         } 
         else if (selectedValues.length > 0) {
             for (var i = 0; i < selectedValues.length; i++) {
                 var message = createSLMessage(
                     "/topics/" + ### WHAT GOES HERE? ###
                 )
             sendMessage(message);
             }
         }
  });
```

#### For reference, here is the jQuery that is creating the list

```
populateList = function() {
     $.getJSON("/assets/JSON/schools.JSON", function(result) {
         $.each(result, function(i){
         var schools = result.schools;
         var output = "";
             for (var i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) {
                 output += "<option>" + schools[i].topic + "</option>";
             }
             $("#schoolSelect").html(output);
         });
     })
 };
```

#### Here is the html of the table (though less important) for reference

```
<select
  size="100"
  multiple
  id="schoolSelect"
  class="school_select"
  ></select>
```

I would like the function selectedOption to actually output the text. If I place console.log where the ### WHAT GOES HERE ### tag is in the function selectedOption itself and then call the selectedOption() later, the console indeed logs the correct value from the select list. I am losing my mind a little because I know there has to be some simple way to do this I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Are you trying to `return` the text?

Comment: @guest271314 Hahahahaha holy crap yes, that's all I wanted to do. I had tried to return it inside the function and obvs it broke...What a dumb mistake on my part lol. I've been grappling with trying to get this converted over from static text files to using JSON and this would have been the easiest part had I looked up for one second and taken a 1/4 of a step back. Thank you!

Comment: @guest271314 if you'd like to just pop return in the ### WHAT GOES HERE ### inside the selectedOption function I'm happy to mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @guest271314 sorry meant copy/paste that portion of the code in there and provide it as an answer, I'll mark it accepted.